# Why is my combobox failing to bind to my List<string> in my ViewModel? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have four Comboboxes in my XAML.  It looks like this:

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding VehiclesAvailable}"  DisplayMemberPath="FleetNumber"/>
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees_VehicleEligible}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName"/>
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Jobsites}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCondition}" />
```

The first three CBs are bound to ObservableCollection properties, and these work fine.
The last is bound to a List, and it is not displaying any content.

In the VM, I declare the property and set its value in a LoadInitialData command.

```
    //PROPERTIES
    public ObservableCollection<VehicleModel> VehiclesAvailable { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> Employees_VehicleEligible { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<JobsiteModel> Jobsites { get; set; }
    public ConditionsModel Conditions { get; set; }
    public GenericCondition SelectedConditionOut { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCondition { get; set; }

    //COMMANDs
    public RelayCommand<object> LoadIntialDataCommand { get; set; }

    //METHODS
    public async void LoadInitialData(object e)
    {
        var vehiclesAvailable = await GetData.VehiclesAvailableQueryAsync();
        foreach (VehicleModel _vehicle in vehiclesAvailable)
            VehiclesAvailable.Add(_vehicle);
        var employees_VehiclesEligible = await GetData.Employees_VehiclesEligibleQueryAsync();
        foreach (EmployeeModel _employee in employees_VehiclesEligible)
            Employees_VehicleEligible.Add(_employee);
        Conditions = new ConditionsModel();
    }
```

And for what it's worth, this is where I define the ConditionsModel:

```
 class ConditionsModel
    {
        private List<string> _conditions;

        public List<string> Conditions
        {
            get { return new List<string>() { "New", "Excellent", "Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Unacceptable" }; }
            set { _conditions = value; }
        }
```

When I step through the code, placing a break point at the closing bracket of the LoadInitialData method, Conditions appears to have all the strings populated.  And when I go to the XAML, sure enough, all the strings appear when I hover over the ItemsSource property.  But when I run it, the combobox is empty.  What might be my next step to debug this problem?

Comment: Can you try calling OnPropertyChanged("Conditions") when setting `Conditions`? => set { _conditions = value; OnPropertyChanged("Conditions"); }

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, Raya, but it didn't work.  And if it did work, that would mean my model class inheriting from my base viewmodel, and that can't be right, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Conditions` property that you currently bind to doesn't return an `IEnumerable` which is required for the `ItemsSource` property.

You should bind to the `Conditions` list property of the `ConditionsModel`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions.Conditions}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCondition}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that your binding to a `ConditionsModel` and not the `ConditionsModel.Conditions` property.
Aside from that `ObservableCollection` will trigger a `NotifyPropertyChange` event when it is updated whereas a standard `List` won't.

Being triggered by a `RelayCommand` your `LoadInitialData(...)` function is going to be called after the View has been created and displayed. If you had created and populated your `Conditions` in your ViewModel constructor then it's possible that you would see some values.

In this situation you may be better off having a `ConditionsViewModel Conditions` instead of a `ConditionsModel Conditions` property, where the `ConditionsViewModel` uses an `ObservableCollection<string> Conditions` and then bind to `ConditionsViewModel.Conditions`